# Knowing precision on one data set, can I make claims about precision on another?

Tags: classification, precision-recall

I am building a spam classifier for email.

Let's say I have 3 million emails and I have a hypothesis that 1% of them are spam.  So, I expect 30,000 of these 3 million emails to be spam but I don't know which ones.

Now, lets say I randomly choose 1 million of these emails and label them using a classifier I've trained.  My classifier predicts that 40,000 of these 1 million are spam.  I go review those 40,000 and find that only 10,000 of them are actually spam.

So, my precision is 10,000 out of 40,000 or 25%.

Now, let's say I go review those 3 million emails manually and find that my initial guess is correct and 30,000 of them actually are spam.

Can I make any guesses about what the precision of my classifier would be given another set of email with different distribution?  Say 50% spam? 20% spam?

On one hand, it seems like precision says nothing except how my classifier did on this particular data set.  But, on the other hand, it seems that if my classifier has a precision of 25% on a data set that was only 1% spam then surely it will do better on a data set that is 50% spam!

Is this logic flawed?